# I can't exec a job with linked server data in SQL Server 2008R2?

Tags: sql-server, jobs, linked-server

I was trying to make replication with local and online DB on HostGator dedicated server, with no solution because of security?

Now, I'm trying to run SQL Server job to execute a procedure for inserting data from local server DB to online server DB and vice-versa, also

I got an error like the attached image (i think security error)
note: I use (sa) account and its privilege was an admin

[image]

error:

> 02/11/2019 20:12:00,run wt stored,Error,1,AABUZEID,run wt
>   stored,runn,,Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. Login failed for
>   user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18456).  The step
>   failed.,00:00:01,14,18456,,,,0

Comment: Its suggested to use hyperlinks instead of direct links in post.

Comment: Please include the text of the message in the question (images are too hard to read).

Comment: thanks a lot, Muhammad, Richard -- check it again plz